# Unsupported Media Type Error with Content-Type

Tags: java, xml, rest, web-services, put

I wrote this piece of code to send a XML request to a server, when I was using

```
"text/xml; charset=utf8"
```

I was getting Unsupported Media Type Error (415). I changed it to

```
"application/xml"
```

and it started to work. I thought they both were the virtually the same and inter-changeable? Am I incorrect in my understanding of the two types?

Comment: This is dependent on whether the unprocessed, source XML document is readable or unreadable by a casual user.

Comment: @Chognificent When you say not readable, does it mean namespaces, and namepspace prefix? Do they make it unreadable to a casual user?